# MAMP Pro 2.2 not reading httpd.conf changes

Tags: php, apache, mamp, lamp, mamp-pro

I'm using MAMP Pro Version 2.2. When I make changes the my httpd.conf file, those changes are not reflected in the httpd.conf file generated by MAMP PRO when I restart its servers.

Through Terminal, I've confirmed that the httpd.conf file MAMP PRO is reading from is /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf. When I make changes to that file, they are not reflected in the generated httpd.conf file that Apache reads from (located at /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/httpd.conf.

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why my changes are not being read in the generated httpd.conf file. Anybody ever run into this issue?

Answer (score 3):

From the MAMP pro knowledge base:

> Q: Changes to my php.ini file and/or my httpd.conf file are not showing up when I restart MAMP PRO.
>
> A: You must edit the httpd.conf, php.ini and my.cnf files through the Template Editor provided by MAMP PRO. Go to File->Edit Template to edit template files.

http://support.appsolute.de/entries/51112025-Changes-to-my-php-ini-file-and-or-my-httpd-conf-file-are-not-showing-up-when-I-restart-MAMP-PRO-